# How to display pairwise comparisons for two groups in a batch ggstatsplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the code that I took from the example:

```
set.seed(123)
library(ggstatsplot)



    grouped_ggbetweenstats(
      data = dplyr::filter(ggplot2::mpg, drv != "4",displ==2),
      x = year,
      y = hwy,
      grouping.var = drv,
    )
```

I need to output a comparison between two groups
After reading the documentation I added:

```
set.seed(123)
library(ggstatsplot)

# the most basic function call
grouped_ggbetweenstats(
  data = dplyr::filter(ggplot2::mpg, drv != "4",displ==2),
  x = year,
  y = hwy,
  grouping.var = drv,
  pairwise.comparisons = T,
  pairwise.display = "all",
  p.adjust.method = "BH"
)
```

But the display of the comparison lines between the groups did not appear. Is it possible to somehow output them in this package ? For 3 or more groups, they are output, but not for 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue on `ggstatsplot`'s GitHub repo that answers this very question:
https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot/issues/605

```r
set.seed(123)
library(ggstatsplot)
library(ggsignif)

# displaying only one comparison
ggbetweenstats(mtcars, am, wt) +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("0", "1")))
#> Warning in wilcox.test.default(c(3.215, 3.44, 3.46, 3.57, 3.19, 3.15, 3.44, :
#> cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

You can decide whether to turn off `ggstatsplot`'s own analysis using the argument `results.subtitle`. It defaults to `TRUE`, but if you change it to `FALSE`, it will show only the *p*-value in the pairwise comparison.

```r
set.seed(123)
library(ggstatsplot)
library(ggsignif)

# displaying only one comparison
ggbetweenstats(mtcars, am, wt, results.subtitle = FALSE) +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("0", "1")))
#> Warning in wilcox.test.default(c(3.215, 3.44, 3.46, 3.57, 3.19, 3.15, 3.44, :
#> cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, but can I somehow pass the form: "p=...."?

Comment: I figured it out, no need)

Comment: Why the p-values computed by `geom_signif` vs `ggstatplots` are different?